# Collider not detecting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class refuelDetect : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button button;
    public Text text;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

For whatever reason this won't change the button to active. It's off, so that works. I also have one collider as the trigger (The one this script is on) and the other one just a normal collider. But for whatever reason, I'm not getting any feedback?

Comment: How do you move your objects? Also please show us the Inspector settings of both objects

Comment: i can really show the inspector settings cause i dont know an image hosting site but for my trigger:
Sphere collider
Is Trigger (checked)
Material: none
Center
X 1.683571 Y 1.143495e Z 3.841168e
Radius 44.51513
For my normal collider:
Box collider
Is Trigger: (Not checked:
Material: None
Center
X: 2.027646 Y: 3.488109 Z: 0.211923
Size:
X: 28.82299 Y: 7.976205 Z: 7.033923

I dont have any rigidbodies or gravity cause it is a space simulation. I move my ships and stuff with transform.Translate(x,y,z) so i dont think it would be an issue to that

Comment: You can add images here .. it will use Imgur as host ;) simply edit your question and press the image button in the text editor

Comment: nvm i found one:
https://ibb.co/F3t7wKD <- Ship
(ignore the collider detection script it was another failed attempt with bad programming)
https://ibb.co/NV7HW0H <- Trigger Collider Object
https://ibb.co/McxDdfs <- Movement

Comment: You have two static colliders, they won't collide, see [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) for an overview matrix of the different colliders. Also, why is the spaceship collider a trigger? You could add a rigidbody to one of the gameobjects. Lastly, why the variable names like that?

Comment: so i HAVE to have a rigidbody?

Comment: @UV-AL Yes, either one rigidbody and a static collider or two rigidbodies work.